# ASP.NET WEB API Not able to retrieve Post Parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I trying to retrieve post parameters in web API but I do get null values everytime.

My html

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:16192/update" name="myform">
  <input name="title" type="text"/>
  <input name="isbn" type="text"/>
  <input name="author" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

And My WebAPI

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UPDATE/")]
    public String updateRecord([FromBody]String title,String isbn="", String author="")
    {
        return "Updated";
    }
```

The `updateRecord` method is being called but I always get null values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UPDATE/")]
public String updateRecord([FromBody]dynamic values)
{
    var title = values.title.Value;
    ....
    return "Updated";
}
```

or you can create a DTO object (paragraph 2):
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Comment: Thenk you for the quick response. But I still don't get the values.
When I try to retrieve values.title.Value I get an error `'values.title' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'`

Comment: @ram2013 if you inspect values while debugging which properties you see?

Comment: I don't see any values/properties for the variable `values`. I just see it as an object

Comment: @ram2013 try to use a DTO maybe there are some conversion problem. Use fiddler to see how the data are sent